# How to count the number of glyphs in NSLayoutManager

Tags: ios, swift, glyph, nslayoutmanager

How do I get the total number of glyphs that are in `NSLayoutManager`?

I was making a cursor layer to overlay on a custom text view like this:

```
func moveCursorToGlyphIndex(glyphIndex: Int) {

    // get bounding rect for glyph
    var rect = self.layoutManager.boundingRectForGlyphRange(NSRange(location: glyphIndex, length: 1), inTextContainer: view.textContainer)
    rect.origin.y = self.textContainerInset.top
    rect.size.width = cursorWidth

    // set cursor layer frame to right edge of rect
    cursorLayer.frame = rect
}
```

However, I wanted to make sure that `glyphIndex` is not out of bounds. Something like this:

```
if glyphIndex < self.layoutManager.glyphCount { // doesn't work
    // ...
}
```

I couldn't find the right property by trial and error, though, and searching online didn't show any SO answers.

I finally did find it in buried in the documentation (and now it seems obvious), but since it took a long time, I decided I would add a Q&A here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `numberOfGlyphs` property, as in

```
layoutManager.numberOfGlyphs
```

This is demonstrated in the Text Layout Programming Guide documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html).